# Encoding in mvc 3 metadata

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encoding

I have an issue with encoding in my app. Text in *.cshtml files is fine but text in metadata comes on page in wrong encoding.

Globalisation setting in web.config looks like:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru-RU" fileEncoding="windows-1251"/>
```

Project is written on ASP.NET MVC 3 and work fine on another server. All text on my website is in russian.

Are there any other settings which i need to set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this problem has nothing to do with mvc, metadata or asp.net. It's an issue of visual studio which saves files in different encoding.

The is an option in VS to save files in unicode:
Options -> Environment -> Documents -> Save documents as Unicode when data cannot be saved in codepage.

Answer (score 0):

So, this option should be checked or not?

Comment: Yeah, it should be checked if you want VS to save all your files in unicode.